# I have a Windows Server with RRAS with NAT but passive FTP doesn't work

Tags: routing, ftp, nat, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019. RRAS with VPN and NAT installed and configured.

I can access any FTP site from the server.

But using passive FTP from any client doesn't work. I get a timeout.

Access to any web site works.

Any idea?

PS.1: I already deactivated the RRAS and configured it again, but no avail.

PS.2: Disabling the Firewall doesn't help either. For testing purpose no other firewall except the Windows Firewall ist running.

PS.3: From the RRAS server I can use any FTP connection I want. So firewall isn't an issue here.

Comment: Why do you want to use a protocol that is so outdated (51 yrs old!) and insecure?

Comment: @Gantendo When I want to access files at my IPS I need to use FTP+SSL...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Nothing special. What do you mean? I just enabled NAT in the configuration for the specific interface. Nothing else is done. On the client the IP of the RRAS server is used as a gateway.

Comment: @xMRi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol & 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS & 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol which one are we talking about? Oldskool FTP? FTP-SSL aka FTPS? SFTP? I wouldn't recommend using FTP... Can you confirm if the ports are open and forwarded?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1701ae63-4e5e-4133-bab7-a0bdba82a154/passive-mode-ftp-server-behind-rras-nat?forum=winserverNAP & https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/092bc52b-3a64-4c54-a19a-8c59adafb92f/rras-and-ftp-server-conflicting?forum=winserverNIS

Comment: FTP with explicit SSL. The links doesn't help, because I already disabled the firewall and it doesn't work either. Also I can tell you that it already worked up to last week...

Answer (score 0):

The problem wan an enabled FTP Proxy on the RRAS server.

I need to disable this and it works. This is done with the following command:

```
netsh routing ip nat delete ftp
```

And here is the description of this command - "Disables the FTP proxy on the NAT server."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754535(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_106

In fact I have no clue how this proxy was enabled...